# Problema em ler float em C

Tags: c

Não sei o que estou fazendo errado.. criei as 3 variáveis (nome, idade, peso), mas na hora de ler o peso o programa encerra e não lê.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    char nome[50];
    int idade;
    float peso;
    printf("<<< EX003 - DADOS >>>\n\n");
    printf("Qual é o seu nome? ");
    gets(nome);
    printf("Quantos anos você têm? ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", idade);
    printf("Qual é o seu peso(Kg)? ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%f", peso);

    printf("-------------------------------------------------");
    printf("Muito prazer, %s. Você tem %d anos e pesa %fKg correto?", nome, idade, peso);
    printf("\nFIM.");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não use `fflush` na entrada. Sequer está definido. Não use `gets`: foi marcada como obsoleta há uma década e nem existe em certos ambientes. Seu erro maior aqui é não consumir os dados corretamente --- os `\n`---  e não tratar o retorno de `scanf`. Veja no manual. Sugiro fazer o simples e usar `fgets` e `atoi`, `atod` e família.

Comment: Onde eu posso encontrar o manual?

Comment: Se estiver usando Linux use `man scanf` por exemplo. Faz parte do sistema. Quando isso foi criado quase todo mundo que usava um computador era programador. E Isso foi antes do Windows e das janelinhas bonitinhas. No Windows tem Linux hoje em dia, basta instalar da loja com um click, então dá na mesma. E pode usar sites como [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)

Comment: Se precisar apenas ver os parâmetros da função qualquer IDE mostra isso hoje: basta parar o mouse sobre a função

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está faltando o "&" para atribuir o valor do scanf à variável de destino. Fica assim:

```
printf("Quantos anos você têm? ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d", &idade);
printf("Qual é o seu peso(Kg)? ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%f", &peso);
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).